# C++ Template recursion that recurses over indices of a boolean function arguments and evaluates function (template meta-programming)

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I am interested in evaluating a boolean function, `F` that takes in N number of boolean arguments. N corresponds to the number of elements in a tuple, `Levels`. I want to perform a compile-time computation that ensures that `F` always evaluates to false. The base case is `F(false, false, ..., false)`, where each argument passed in is `false`. However, for each element in `Levels`, if it meets a certain condition, I want to also evaluate `F` with `true` input corresponding to the index of that element in `Levels`.

For example, say Levels = (A, B, C, D). And A and D meet the condition. We want to check that the output is always false for F evaluated:

```
    F(false, false, false, false) must == false
    F(true, false, false, false) must == false
    F(false, false, false, true) must == false
```

If any `F` evaluations returns `true`, then this should raise a `static_assert` error. Some pseudocode for the structure would be:

```
template <class F, class... Levels>
class Coiterate<F, std::tuple<Levels...>>
    {
    public:
        explicit inline Coiterate(F f, Levels&... levels)
        {
             // run the validation with respect to F and Levels
             compile_time_validate<F, Levels>();
        }
     }
```

I am sure a pattern like this has a name in C++ template-meta-programming, but I had a hard time googling on SO. If anyone has any links to other posts that address this concept, then that would also be helpful. I would like to implement the `compile_time_check` function. My attempt at some pseudocode that would solve this at runtime is:

```
// I want to perform the compile-time check here F and Levels, something along these lines

// first evaluate with all inputs `false`
static_assert(F(false, false, ..., false) == false);
for idx, level in enumerate(Levels):
    if constexpr meet_condition(level):
        input_arg = true;
        static_assert(F(false, ..., input_arg, false, ..., false) == false);
     else:
          // do nothing because we only need to evaluate it with `true` at index idx if the condition is met.
```

[Update - details on function F] The function `F` is a boolean function that basically defines a set of conjunctions/disjunctions always.

For example:

```
// this is a conjunction (A \cap B) over two input Levels
auto fn1 = [](std::tuple<bool, bool> t) constexpr { return std::get<0>(t) && std::get<1>(t); };

// this is a combined disjunction and conjunction over four input levels
auto fn2 = [](std::tuple<bool, bool, bool, bool> t) constexpr
    { (return (std::get<0>(t) && std::get<2>(t) && std::get<1>(t)) || std::get<3>(t)); };
```

Let's take `F` as `fn2`, then say the inputs correspond to `Levels = (A, B, C, D)` and A and D meet some condition, say `A::condition_met`, then I would want to check the following:

```
1. static_assert(F(false, false, false, false) == false)
2. static_assert(F(true, false, false, false) == false)

// note that in this case, the static_assert would fail because
// there is an "OR" operation with a `true` value.
3. static_assert(F(false, false, false, true) == false)
```

It is assumed that `condition_met` is defined during compile-time for each level in `Levels`, so this is just a matter of expanding and evaluating `F` for a series of different boolean input arguments.

Comment: I always wonder why posts like this get so many downvotes.. He did show research effort and provided a clear question!

Comment: I'm confused. What did I do wrong? Isn't this a valid question?

Comment: @EldinurtheKolibri The Q is unclear and has the scent of XY-problem.

Comment: @ajl123 Could you please give an example of a specific condition for which a specific `F(...)` might evaluate to `true` for some level? This is just for illustrative purposes, to make the question clearer. // Others: 3 downvotes without anyone leaving a comment about how to improve this is not okay!

Comment: @273K I have added an explicit example regarding F. I can see where the confusion might lie if the question was not well specified enough. Hopefully this helps?

Comment: false&&B is always false regardless of B value - you are solving this requirement/concept, right? It's more close to X, but you are still solving Y.

Comment: @273K Yes `false && B` is always false regardless of `B` being true, or false. However, `(false && B && C) || D` can be false, or true depending on the value of D. I am trying to verify that the input Levels are valid with respect to the boolean function input during compile-time. I don't even have a valid soln. so unsure how this is an XY problem... I can do this during runtime, but the question is how to do this during compile-time.

Comment: I don't understand which combinations you want to check. Some arguments are always false, and for other you want to check all combinations of `true` and `false`? If yes, why is `F(true, false, false, true) must == false` missing from the example?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I just added some details to the question that hopefully clarify this. I want to iterate through each element/argument in `zip(Levels, F_args)`, if the level meets a condition, I want to evaluate `F` with the input now being `true` for that specific level. All other inputs are always `false`. I do not want to check all combinations of `true/false`.

Comment: @ajl123 `fn2` does not compute `(A && B && C) || D` currently. In fact, it would not compile. Probably a typo.

Comment: I've been staring at this for awhile but I don't even know what to ask. Since you want to do this validation at compile-time, wouldn't it be easier to _not_ send in runtime `bool`eans but to do it all with template parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, this would work:

```
template <typename F, typename... Levels>
void coiterate(F f, Levels const&...) {
    static_assert(f(std::make_tuple((Levels{}, false)...)) == false);

    [&]<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        constexpr auto make_single_level_tuple = []<std::size_t I>(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>) constexpr {
            constexpr auto levels_tuple = std::make_tuple(Levels{}...);
            constexpr auto false_tuple = std::make_tuple((Levels{}, false)...);
            return std::make_tuple(std::get<Is>(I == Is ? levels_tuple : false_tuple)...);
        };

        static_assert(((f(make_single_level_tuple(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Is>{})) == false) && ...));
    }(std::index_sequence_for<Levels...>{});
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ddaPjasd5)

`levels_tuple` is a tuple of "condition met" for each level. `false_tuple` is a tuple of false of the same size. `make_single_level_tuple` makes a tuple of false except at index `I`, where it takes from `levels_tuple` instead. The rest is just a matter of calling `f` with the correct tuples, and asserting the conjunction of the results.